# Disable annoying website HTML5 push notifications to chrome / firefox browsers

Tags: google-chrome, popups

Recently I've been getting notification popups on certain websites. I don't know if I accidentally clicked it or not, but its really annoying. I found that you can disable all of this completely in the "content settings" of chrome, but I want to leave it on with permission to ask. I couldn't find the stupid site in the list of "exceptions", but found a http://* wildcard indicating its being set by a plugin. But problem is WHAT PLUGIN? I want to remove this site from notifying me. Is there a way to do this?

I also checked off **"Do Not allow any site to show notifications"** in chrome and it still showing up.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, disable all the extensions and see if you can remove it. if you can, enable one extension and check again. repeat until you find the extention that is causing the problem.